# How to try every possible permutation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, permutation, brute-force

```
fun main () {
    var integers = mutableListOf(0)
    for (x in 1..9) {
        integers.add(x)
    }
    //for or while could be used in this instance
    var lowerCase = listOf("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z")
    var upperCase = listOf('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z')
    println(integers)
    println(lowerCase)
    println(upperCase)
    //Note that for the actual program, it is also vital that I use potential punctuation
    val passwordGeneratorKey1 = Math.random()*999
    val passwordGeneratorKey2 = passwordGeneratorKey1.toInt()
    var passwordGeneratorL1 = lowerCase[(Math.random()*lowerCase.size).toInt()]
    var passwordGeneratorL2 = lowerCase[(Math.random()*lowerCase.size).toInt()]
    var passwordGeneratorL3 = lowerCase[(Math.random()*lowerCase.size).toInt()]
    var passwordGeneratorU1 = upperCase[(Math.random()*upperCase.size).toInt()]
    var passwordGeneratorU2 = upperCase[(Math.random()*upperCase.size).toInt()]
    var passwordGeneratorU3 = upperCase[(Math.random()*upperCase.size).toInt()]
    val password = passwordGeneratorKey2.toString()+passwordGeneratorL1+passwordGeneratorL2+passwordGeneratorL3+passwordGeneratorU1+passwordGeneratorU2+passwordGeneratorU3
    println(password)
    //No, this isn't random, but it's pretty close to it
    //How do I now run through every possible combination of the lists //lowerCase, integers, and upperCase?
}
```

How do I run through every possible permutation to eventually solve for the randomly generated password? This is in Kotlin.

Comment: I'm going to be honest with you, this is going to be a computationally dififficult task. Is there a limit to how long you want it to run for? EG. Char maximum?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you try to achieve. A fully random password with exactly one digit, 3 lower case letters and 3 upper case letters?

Comment: https://github.com/CyanCoding/Brute-Force-Password-Cracker/blob/master/Kotlin/bruteforcepasswordcracker.kt

Answer (score 0):

I think you should append all the lists together and then draw from it by random index, this way you ensure that position of numbers, lower cases and uppercases is random too. Also you don't need to write all the characters, you can use `Range` which generates them for you.

```
    fun main() {
        val allChars = mutableListOf<Any>().apply {
            addAll(0..9) // creates range from 0 to 9 and adds it to a list
            addAll('a'..'z') // creates range from a to z and adds it to a list
            addAll('A'..'Z') // creates range from A to Z and adds it to a list
        }
        val passwordLength = 9
        val password = StringBuilder().apply {
            for (i in 0 until passwordLength) {
                val randomCharIndex =
                    Random.nextInt(allChars.lastIndex) // generate random index from 0 to lastIndex of list
                val randomChar = allChars[randomCharIndex] // select character from list
                append(randomChar) // append char to password string builder 
            }
        }.toString()
    
        println(password)
    }
```

Even shorter solution can be achieved using list methods

```
 fun main() {
    val password = mutableListOf<Any>()
        .apply {
            addAll(0..9) // creates range from 0 to 9 and adds it to a list
            addAll('a'..'z') // creates range from a to z and adds it to a list
            addAll('A'..'Z') // creates range from A to Z and adds it to a list
        }
        .shuffled() // shuffle the list
        .take(9) // take first 9 elements from list
        .joinToString("") // join them to string 
    println(password)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out there are less painful ways to generate the initial password in the format of: 1 to 3 digits followed by 3 lowercase characters followed by 3 uppercase characters.

To brute force this password, you will need to consider all 3-permutations of `"a..z"` and all 3-permitations of `"A..Z"`. In both cases the number of such 3-permutations is `15600 = 26! / (26-3)!`. In worst case you will have to examine `1000 * 15600 * 15600` combination, half of this on the average.

Probably doable in a few hours with the code below:

```kotlin
import kotlin.random.Random
import kotlin.system.exitProcess


val lowercaseList = ('a'..'z').toList()
val uppercaseList = ('A'..'Z').toList()

val lowercase = lowercaseList.joinToString(separator = "")
val uppercase = uppercaseList.joinToString(separator = "")

fun genPassword(): String {
    val lowercase = lowercaseList.shuffled().take(3)
    val uppercase = uppercaseList.shuffled().take(3)

    return (listOf(Random.nextInt(0, 1000)) + lowercase + uppercase).joinToString(separator = "")
}


/**
 * Generate all K-sized permutations of str of length N. The number of such permutations is:
 * N! / (N-K)!
 *
 * For example: perm(2, "abc") =  [ab, ac, ba, bc, ca, cb]
 */
fun perm(k: Int, str: String): List<String> {

    val nk = str.length - k

    fun perm(str: String, accumulate: String): List<String> {
        return when (str.length == nk) {
            true -> listOf(accumulate)
            false -> {
                str.flatMapIndexed { i, c ->
                    perm(str.removeRange(i, i + 1), accumulate + c)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return perm(str, "")
}

fun main() {
    val password = genPassword().also { println(it) }

    val all3LowercasePermutations = perm(3, lowercase).also { println(it) }.also { println(it.size) }
    val all3UppercasePermutations = perm(3, uppercase).also { println(it) }.also { println(it.size) }


    for (i in 0..999) {
        println("trying $i")
        for (l in all3LowercasePermutations) {
            for (u in all3UppercasePermutations) {
                if ("$i$l$u" == password) {
                    println("found: $i$l$u")
                    exitProcess(0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```